# How to count nested object value with angular.forEach?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, for-loop

my object :

```
service: {
    categories: [0: {
            name: "category1",
            id: 2,
            questions: [0: {
                id: 1,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 1
            }]]
    }
```

Basically, I need to find where there is a value present in a statement and count it.

```
$scope.questionCount = 0;

angular.forEach($scope.service, function(categories, questions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    if (questions[i].value !== null){
      $scope.questionCount += 1
    }
}
});
```

this is what I've tried, but when I console.log, I"m still getting 0.  I'm looping incorrectly or not checking the value correctly. Any help, appreciated.

Comment: It is invalid object, you must be seeing a syntax error or if it is json it is invalid too.

Comment: This is more of just a JavaScript question, it is not Angular-specific. If  you don't get good enough answers, perhaps try re-asking it without Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your data object doesn't make much sense (to me at least). For the reminder of my answer I'll assume your object looks something like this:

```
var categories = [
    {
        name: "category1",
        id: 1,
        questions: [
            {
                id: 1,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 2
            }, {
                id: 2,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 3
            }]
    },
    {
        name: "category2",
        id: 2,
        questions: [
            {
                id: 3,
                question: "example trivia question here",
                value: 5
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "category3",
        id: 3
    }
];
```

Counting the number of questions in this object can be done in a number of ways, either by looping through the questions as you have attempted, or by using e.g. a reduce function like this:

```
$scope.questionCount = categories.reduce(function(prev, curr){
    return (curr.questions) ? prev.concat(curr.questions) : prev;
}, []).length;
```

This will extract the question array from each category and concatenate them all into one array. The total number of questions is the `length` of this array, in this case 3.

You can read more about the reduce function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

If you want to sum each questions' `value` property you can sprinkle it with some more map/reduce magic, like this:

```
$scope.questionCount = categories
        .reduce(function(prev, curr){
            return (curr.questions) ? prev.concat(curr.questions) : prev;
        }, [])
        .map(function(q){ 
            return (q.value)? q.value : 0;
        })
        .reduce(function(prev, curr){
            return prev + curr;
        }, 0);
```

The first reduce is exactly the same as in the previous example. The `map` function transforms the array of questions into an array with only the values from the `value` property, i.e. [2,3,5]. The second `reduce` sums these numbers. In this case `$scope.questionCount` will be 10.

Map function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the `angular.forEach` loop in your snippet is complete nonsense.

[Please read it up here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach). `angular.forEach` is used to loop through object keys (like how `Array.prototype.forEach` loop through array index).

Hint: a proper solution to this does not even needs `angular.forEach`: you can simply do it with `Array.prototype.forEach`. [Please read it up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you want to learn how to use it.

Furthermore even in your normal for-loop you should use `i` as the index since `questions` is an array, and do it with `++` if you want to add 1 to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$scope.questionCount + 1;
```

does nothing. You should do

```
$scope.questionCount += 1;
```

or

```
$scope.questionCount++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the new value, `$scope.questionCount += 1` or `$scope.questionCount++`;